# search and extract a string of Chinese characters by start and end value (python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string file that I scraped from the web:

```
text="\r\n欽定四庫全書\r\n\u3000唐會要卷二\r\n\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000宋\u3000王溥\u3000撰\r\n\u3000\u3000帝號下\r\n文宗元聖昭獻孝皇帝諱昻穆宗第二子母曰/貞獻皇后蕭氏\r\n元和四年己丑歳十月十日生以其日為/慶成節"
```

Note that the text has some backslashes and `\r\n`. I would like to extract some text by start and end value, for example: from `"唐會要卷二"` (the last five characters in the first row) to `"元和四年"` (towards the end of the third row).

Expected output:

```
"唐會要卷二\r\n\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000\u3000宋\u3000王溥\u3000撰\r\n\u3000\u3000帝號下\r\n文宗元聖昭獻孝皇帝諱昻穆宗第二子母曰/貞獻皇后蕭氏\r\n元和四年"
```

what I have tried:

```py
import re
re.findall("唐會要卷二.*元和四年",text)
```

which returns an empty list. I suspect it has something to do with the backslashes and the `\r\n`; I tried to remove them and redo the search, but still get nothing.

Any thoughts/suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: `\r\n` means `new line` (and it is one of `whitespaces`, togeterh with `space`, `tab`) and using `text = text.strip()` you can remove all whitespaces from both ends.

Comment: Is your input string raw ? If so, your regex will match.  If not, did you convert your expected output back into string mode, `\u####` and all ?

Answer (score 0):

`\r\n` means `new line` so you have text with many lines and you search text which has also `\r\n` - so you search `multiline` result - but normally `regex` searchs only in single line - dot `.` doesn't match `\n` - and it may need flag `re.DOTALL` to search in `multiline`.

```
re.findall("唐會要卷二.*元和四年", text, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!